# CSS modules and rollup - generating separate CSS files ("themes") with same hashes

Tags: css, rollup, css-modules

I'm using CSS Modules (Sass) with rollup on a component library project, which is working well. Each component ends up with a dist folder containing a single JS bundle file, and a corresponding CSS file with the scoped CSS classes so consumers of the component don't have to worry about CSS class name conflicts. All they do is include the JS bundle and the CSS file and everything is great. Yay CSS Modules.

The problem I'm now facing is that some components really need separate "themes" - ideally, separate CSS files, one per theme. So consumers can continue as they've been doing: including the JS bundle, but now choosing which CSS file to include to pick a theme.

I'm not sure how to get this going with CSS modules & rollup, and whether this is even the sort of approach others are taking. From what I can see, rollup always handles bundling things together, whereas I want *separate* CSS files, all of which get their classes renamed identically during the build phase. That way, if within my JS I refer to `styles.myclass`, if `myclass` had gotten renamed to `scoped-myclass` by CSS modules for the original CSS file, for a second CSS file it would also get the same name.

This would keep consumption of the component extremely simple - just a matter of including a different CSS file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awfully late, but let me answer this 3 years on. So what I ended up doing was totally detaching the CSS generation step from rollup and relying on the Sass CLI to handle that portion of the build process. It felt a bit klutzy, but I remember it wasn't awfully hard to do and solved the problem I outlined above. I don't believe there was a plain rollup solution at the time, nor do I think there's one today.

*However*... in my case the whole approach was kinda mistaken. This certainly won't be everyone's scenario, but let me spell it all out because hey it may be useful and it definitely wasn't obvious to me at the time.

This was for an in-house shared component library, where each component and its corresponding CSS was a separate npm package stored in our Artifactory. When it grew, plenty of internal references popped up, e.g. multiple components would reference the Button component, and over time they'd reference different *versions* of the Buttons component - each of which needed its own properly scoped CSS, unique to that package-version.

So what I found was that by doing it this way - having the CSS generated as part of the npm package dist files - I had to write an additional layer for the *consumer* applications that would parse their node_modules/ folder for our own internal components and combine all the different CSS files, such as the multiple versions of buttons. e.g. the main application would directly import buttons v1.0.0 in its package.json file, but the Dialog component (also included in the package.json) could include buttons 2.0.0 as its own dependency. For every version of the package, there was a uniquely scoped version of the CSS - so the consuming application HAD to include every version otherwise the styling would be borked.

So all in all, it ended up being way more complex that I wanted. I thought I could make it easier & better with the separate generated themed CSS files as part of the package dist, but it didn't end up that way. If I could revisit that project today, I'd re-examine a solution used by Material UI and others which I kinda poo-poo'd at the time: automatic injection of the CSS into the page by the component JS, rather than generating standalone CSS files which required extra work by the consumer applications to gather up and add to the final webpage. Frankly, now I regard it as the "least crap". There are definite downsides to the injection approach (extra work done on every page render for *everyone*! Yikes!), but there's no doubt in my mind it hugely simplifies the job of the consumer applications. It's a balancing act, but in 20-20 hindsight I'd lean towards the injection approach. With that, scoping & theming is a different and much simpler problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, consider looking at SCSS plugin: [rollup-plugin-scss](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-scss). It captures all spare `.css` files imported in the components, and then processes them through underlying `node-sass`. The catch is, it seems like you can write a custom callback function that'd handle your CSSs differently based on conditions you throw in.

Based on the example from the plugin's page:

```
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss'
...

export default {
  input: 'src/index.tsx',
  output: [...],
  plugins: [
    ...
    output: function (styles, styleNodes) {
      // replace this with conditioned outputs as needed:
      writeFileSync('bundle1.css', styles)
      writeFileSync('bundle2.css', styles)
    },
  ]
}
```